# Javascript mousedown event location on windows phone

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, windows-phone, jquery-events

I am creating a mobile site that needs to be cross browser compatible. For one feature I need to detect the location of a touch event.

Windows Phone does not support touchstart etc. so I am using mousedown instead, but I am having trouble getting the page position from the event. It works without issue on desktop, and the mousedown is being detected on windows phone, but I can't figure out how to get the offsetX - offset Y.

Here's a sample which works on desktop and on iPhone and android
(I am using jQuery but no plugins or anything non-standard):

```
$("div").on("touchstart mousedown", function(e){
    org_x = e.originalEvent.changedTouches[0].pageX ? e.originalEvent.changedTouches[0].pageX : e.originalEvent.offsetX;
    alert(org_x);

    org_y = e.originalEvent.changedTouches[0].pageY ? e.originalEvent.changedTouches[0].pageY : e.originalEvent.offsetY;
    alert(org_y);
});
```

I have tested this on windows phone 8 and 9

Comment: I don't know if it's any different for touch events or on phones, but why don't you just use `e.pageX` and `e.pageY` - not dealing with the `originalEvent`. I'm pretty sure jQuery normalizes the position of the event so you don't have to do something like this

Comment: e.pageX e.pageY works fine for mousedown mouseup, but on windows phone mousemove is being treated the same as mousedown so its very limiting

Answer (score 1):

try this code ,it will work fine

```
document.getElementById("clickdiv").addEventListener("MSPointerDown",handleDown,false);

function handleDown(evt) {
    alert(evt.originalEvent.layerX);
}

$("#clickdivalt").on("MSPointerDown", handleAltDown);

function handleAltDown(evt){
    alert(evt.originalEvent.layerX);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what i see you want to read this article: [Touch/Gestures On Mobile Devices](http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2011/12/07/touching-and-gesturing-on-iphone-android-and-more/) or have a look at this stack overflow question: [Windows phone 8 touch support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13396297/windows-phone-8-touch-support)

Im still looking arrow and will update my answer with better solutions as i find them!

Comment: thanks for responding. I will have a look through the articles you suggest

Comment: I tried out MSPointerDown etc.  They fire OK, but there doesn't seem to be any position attributes.

Answer (score 0):

The isues width MSPonterDown etc. seem to be a jquery bug/incompatablility. If I set the event handler with pure javascript I can get the pageX and pageY attributes.  If I set the event handler with jquery there is no pageX pageY.

```
document.getElementById("clickdiv").addEventListener("MSPointerDown",handleDown,false);

function handleDown(evt) {
    alert(evt.pageX);
}

$("#clickdivalt").on("MSPointerDown", handleAltDown);

function handleAltDown(evt){
    alert(evt.pageX);
}
```

Comment: evt.originalEvent.layerX will works fine. you should first find properties in response evt first.there you can see a property called originalEvent see properties inside that object you can see layerX .thats what we want..we can use clintX too in place of layerX