# Giving immediate feedback upon touching a touch screen

Tags: html, angularjs, cordova, angularjs-directive

We are using AngularJS, Bootstrap, and Phonegap to build an application targeting predominately the iPad. So far we have been using the Bootstrap list-group-item class. We are finding that upon touching a visual element defined as shown below that there is perhaps a half second lag between the user touching the element, and receiving visual feedback that something happened. Is there a way to code this such that a user gets an immediate feedback - such as highlighting the area - before processing the click event? Giving that instant feedback creates a significant perceptual change in the responsiveness of the application.

```
<a class="list-group-item" ng-click="studentSelectClick(student.student_info.userId)">
    <span ng-bind-template="{{student.student_info.firstName}}
                            {{student.student_info.lastName}}">
    </span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular provides a module, `ngTouch` to sort this issue, caused by certain touch devices. As per the docs at http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngTouch , you should be able to include it in the page:

```
<script src="angular.js">
<script src="angular-touch.js">
```

and then include dependency on the module by:

```
angular.module('app', ['ngTouch']);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is due to how mobile browsers handle clicks. There are two options:

1. Use [fastclick](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick).
2. Set your browser viewport to have no user scalability. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12238587/eliminate-300ms-delay-on-click-events-in-mobile-safari) but note that it doesn't work in mobile safari--you might end up having to go with fastclick instead.