# Safari 300ms delay Apple devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

In my game instant clicking is very important, the 300ms delay is really screwing with my movment on IOS 
Is there anyway to eleminate this? There is no code involved in this one, Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eliminate 300ms delay on click events in mobile Safari](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12238587/eliminate-300ms-delay-on-click-events-in-mobile-safari)

Comment: May be some one can hack UIWebView - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55155560/cordova-disabling-the-click-delay-300ms-click-delay-in-uiwebview

Answer (score 1):

The delay exists on mobile devices to determine if the user is tapping the screen or holding down. There are several libraries you can use to easily circumvent the issue such as [FastClick.js](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick).