# How to simulate vclick using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, click, vclick

This is how I simulate a click in a web browser:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click();
});
```

But how can I simulate a vclick instead? The reason is I want to automate a tap on mobile devices. Any ideas?

Comment: https://api.jquerymobile.com/vclick/
http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: You could probably trigger it if you're using jQuery Mob, `$("button").trigger('vclick')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you can use this:

```
$('button').trigger('vclick');
```

Use vclick with caution! See https://api.jquerymobile.com/vclick/

Update: possible alternative

```
$('button').trigger('tap');
```

See also: [Eliminate 300ms delay on click events in mobile Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12238587/eliminate-300ms-delay-on-click-events-in-mobile-safari)

Update: did you try/know Hammer.js? Take a look at http://hammerjs.github.io/recognizer-tap/ and http://hammerjs.github.io/tips/

Comment: For some reason, this doesn't work. @Henri S. Do you know how else I can simulate a click on a mobile device?